# Activation/Upgrade Error 0x803fa067

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

I tried to Updgrade my windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro.
I tried it with the default key that upgrades Windows 10 to pro without activating it(which is done in the second step).

The Universal-Key for Windows 10 Pro which is published by Microsoft is VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T. I tried that one but I get the error 0x803fa067.

I first tried it with the Windows 10 Settings using the Change Product Key Button in the Activation "Tab" And second with the command slmgr.vbs -ipk  VK7JG-...
Both methods werent succesfull.

What the error originally means is: you don't have a digital licence or a valid Product Key.
I guess either the newly bought laptop was delivered with a fraudulent license( then microsoft is bluntly lying to me)

[image: Microsoft is activated]

or the error message isn't quite correct. In this case I would go with my second guess

I am not sure why this Problem occures, so my question is: why do I get the Error 0x803fa067?
I am aware of the fact that I could reinstall Windows 10 Pro(which is the way I will probably do it) but I am intrigued to know how I could resolve the Problem without spending those extra 15 minutes.

Comment: The generic Windows 10 Professional license key cannot be used to activate Windows 10.  In order to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional from Windows 10 Home you need to have an actual Windows 10 Professional license key, and use the upgrade mechanism, to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional.  If your using sgr.vbs your doing it wrong.

Comment: Searching for “upgrade” should find the core mechanism

Comment: @Ramhound I am not trying to activate with the key, I am trying to upgrade with the key. I have a valid license key with which I tried to activate my windows 10 pro but I have to upgrade it first if I am not mistaken right? Either way it doesn't work with one or the other

Comment: use your correct Win10 pro key to upgrade

Comment: @magicandre1981 As stated above, that doesn't work either

Comment: which error code do yo get when you use your product key?

Comment: @Bongo - I'm experiencing the same issue. I posted a similar question on MS website. Please see my findings here:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/i-am-unable-to-upgrade-win-10-home-to-pro-error/54b2a07f-36a2-4d5a-8853-d25f5f83b906?messageId=3c2ab13b-e456-4771-bf80-b418d3708c0e

Comment: As described in [this blog](http://www.noelpulis.com/fix-windows-10-home-to-pro-upgrade-error-0x803fa067/) and in the post of [JonathanWeinblatt](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/i-am-unable-to-upgrade-win-10-home-to-pro-error/54b2a07f-36a2-4d5a-8853-d25f5f83b906?messageId=3c2ab13b-e456-4771-bf80-b418d3708c0e) the key to the upgrade procedure is to **stop the Internet connection** before typing the Universal key in the Activation "Tab".

Comment: Don't know why it works, but I followed this procedure myself (today and after updating to October version 1809) and the upgrade went smoothly with a couple of restarts. After that I reconnected and entered my bought Win 10 Pro key and everything works fine.